# html input number, min + step, make step ignore min?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Is it possible to make the `step` ignore the `min` attribute?

```
<input type="number" min="2" step="5"/>
```

As it is now, it steps like so: `2, 7, 12, 17, ...`
instead, I'd like it to be: `2, 5, 10, 15, 20, ...`

My real code actually uses dynamic values like so:

```
<input type="number" [min]="someValue" [step]="someStep"/>
```

One way to solve would maybe create a directive to substitute either `min` or `step` to do the same thing without taking into consideration the other attribute.

So is there an easy way to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `step` takes the into account the value of the `min` and `max` attributes. This is default browser behaviour and I don't think it is a good idea to try and circumvent this.

I would add a `data-min` attribute with the value of `2` and set `min` to `0`. Now it is possible to check if the value of the input is less than the custom min value and alter the value when needed.

Because now the minimum value is 0 it means that the browser will follow your desired sequence of `0`, `5`, `10`, `15`, etc.

```js
const
  inputElement = document.getElementById('input');
  
function onValueChanged(event) {
  const 
    customMin = parseInt(inputElement.getAttribute('data-min'), 10),
    value = parseInt(inputElement.value);
    
  if (value > customMin) {
    return;
  }
  
  inputElement.value = customMin;
}

inputElement.addEventListener('change', onValueChanged);
```

```html
<input id="input" type="number" min="0" step="5" data-min="2" value="2"/>
```

Comment: Thank you! I chose this one because this one allows `""` blank, so it's possible to type the value directly. Another reason is: `inputElement.getAttribute('data-min')`, this gave me an idea how I can use this for other things. I'll be using this answer as a guide to make my `step` as I want to keep the `min` for validation stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You can just force the `min` using JS. I did a little experiment, and it works the way you wanted: https://jsfiddle.net/h2n2cmd2/2/

HTML:

```
<input type="number" id="input">
```

JS:

```
var min = 2;
var step = 5;

var inputObj = document.getElementById("input");

inputObj.step = step;

inputObj.oninput = function() {

    if (inputObj.value < min) {
        inputObj.value = min;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up making my "step directive", as I didn't know how I could get a handle to the control to trigger an `.updateValueAndValidity()` and use the `.preventDefault()`, I had to use a work-around which seems to work well: `const fix = isKeyUp ? -1 : 1;`

```
import { Directive, Input, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

const key_arrow_up = 38;
const key_arrow_down = 40;

@Directive({
  selector: '[my-step]'
})
export class MyStepDirective {
  private _step: number;

  @Input() min: number;
  @Input() set myStepArg(value: number) {
    this._step = +value;
  }

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyUp(ke: KeyboardEvent) {
    const isKeyUp = ke.keyCode === key_arrow_up;
    const isKeyDown = ke.keyCode === key_arrow_down;
    // fix: -1/+1 is to cover for default behavior on arrow up/down
    const fix = isKeyUp ? -1 : 1;

    if (isKeyUp || isKeyDown) {
      const value = +ke.target['value'];
      const isValid = value !== undefined && !isNaN(value);
      if (isValid) {
        const nValue = isKeyUp ? this._getNextUp(value) : this._getNextDown(value);
        if (!this.min || nValue >= this.min)
          ke.target['value'] = nValue + fix;
        else
          ke.target['value'] = this.min + fix;
      }
    }
  }

  constructor() {}

  private _getNextUp(current: number): number {
    return current + this._step - (current % this._step);
  }

  private _getNextDown(current: number): number {
    return current - this._step + (current % this._step);
  }

}
```

And in the template, I use it like so:

```
<input type="number" name="cashTendered" required
  my-step [myStepArg]="cashStep" [min]="sale.total">
```

It should be fairly easy to modify so that it can handle `max` as well, if you need it.