# HTML input type number with min constraint and step function not working

Tags: html

as the title says I am currently having an issue with the step function for input type number fields. If i set a min value and step it does not work properly, but if I dont set a min, the step function works properly.

```
Not working <input type="number" min="-999" step="1024">
Not working <input type="number" min="-199999" step="1024">
Not working <input type="number" min="5" step="1024">
Working <input type="number" step="1024">
```

Here is a jsfiddle link that reproduces the issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/72vpdsu0/2/

Comment: why you use `min` describe more

Comment: Refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46145390/html-input-number-min-step-make-step-ignore-min

Comment: Well it does work but not as expected. When clicking the up arrow of the field it does not increase to 1024 but to a smaller value. For instance:
 <input type="number" min="-999" step="1024">
In that case clicking the uparrow goes to 25 instead of 1024. I hope that clarifies my concern.
 @BhargavChudasama I am using min to set a minimum value for the field.

Comment: set min value same as `1024 in minus or plus` than its works

Comment: But I don't want it being the same. That's not the point. I want to have a min="-32767" and a step="1024" for instance.

Comment: so its working according to your `min value`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but the step function works according to the min value constraint.